# Reading structure information from file into an empty array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, structure

I need some help...
I have this data file accounts.txt:

```
stefan 20 50 60
anelia 2130 452 5200
atanas 52.3 560 45
peychev 258 852 654
ivan 1 2 3
petyr 4 5 6
me 48 84 57
you 57 48 56
Jordan 1000 0 0
asd 12 13 14
bdp 15 16 17
```

I need to read the info from the file into an array of structures.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
const int N=1000;
int n;
struct account {
    char name[30];
    double blv;
    double usd;
    double euro;
};
void sortirane (int n);

void main() {
    cin>>n;
    ....
}
```

And this is the function:

```
void sortirane(int n) {
    ifstream file1("accounts.txt");
    if(!file1) { cerr<<"Error!"; return; }
    account b[N];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        file1>>b[i].name>>b[i].blv>>b[i].usd>>b[i].euro;

    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        cout<<b[j].name<<b[j].blv<<b[j].usd<<b[j].euro;
}
```

Unfortunately the array is empty after the end of the first loop...

Comment: Try to do your homework by yourself, then if you have an specific problem ask here, showing us what you have tried. Until that, delete this question since is completely off-topic. Being specific, use a debugger.

Comment: Don't use globals, use `std::string` instead of C char arrays, use `std::vector` in place of raw arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you think the array is empty is because the global `n` is still 0, its because you never changed it (and can't from within `sortirane`, since it has its own `n`).